# Should I call escape_javascript when displaying data fetched from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-4, xss

I have a field that is `xss_sanatised` in the model level before being saved in the database. When I wish to display this should I again `escape_javascript` it before rendering it in the view?

Like should my query be like

`User.all.pluck(:id, :name).map { id: id, name: escape_javascipt(name)}`

instead of

`User.all.pluck(:id, :name).map { id: id, name: name }`

When I directly injected `<script>alert('hi')</script>` in the database it actually executed in the UI.
Although I'd not be able to write that value to the database without directly writing SQL Queries.

So Should I use `escape_javascript` for all fields or not?

**Edit**

This is rendered in the UI as a dropdown list using select2

```
<div input="hidden" id="input"></div>
jQuery('#input').select2({
    multiple: false,
    data: <%=tech.to_json.html_safe%>,
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        callback(<%= esc.to_json.html_safe %>);
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you display it?

Comment: *"To insert something verbatim use the `raw` helper rather than calling `html_safe` or, equivalently, use `<%==`."* - [Active Record Core Extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#safe-strings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're getting confused here simply because you're bypassing your own application's sanitisation rules - by directly writing to the database.

By default, you should never "trust" user input. It should always be considered potentially-malicious.

One reason you may choose to trust it, is if it's supplied by *internal users* (e.g. yourself!).

Or, another reason you may choose to trust it is if you've **sanitised it** before persisting it - i.e. you have explicitly blocked any potentially-malicious input.

Assuming your "`xss_sanatised`" input is safe (which I cannot confirm, since you didn't share the code), then you *can* trust user input as safe. Therefore it's fine to display directly in the browser.

However, if you force unsafe input into the database manually by "directly writing SQL Queries", then naturally the above assumption that "input is safe" becomes invalid. But this is an "impossible" scenario, so isn't something I'd particularly worry about.

If you really want to be doubly-extra-safe about this, then you could re-sanitise input before rendering it. But this is most likely overkill, in my opinion. (You should only need to sanitise it once, either way!)

---

[`escape_javascript`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) is a separate method, that has nothing to do with user input sanitisation. This is irrelevant to the problem you are describing.

If you need to call `escape_javascript` on a value, then go for it. But again, since you didn't share the view rendering code, I cannot advise whether it's actually needed.